# correct HTML pages won't load in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, browser

I'm editing someone elses webpage for content, by changing the HTML files on the drive, adding text, comments, wtv. I'm not a web designer, so this is the only way I knew to do it.

On most browsers, my changes show, but on internet explorer, sometimes it will revert to the old webpage. I can't find the info for the old page anywhere on the drive that holds all of this content. Please steer me in the right direction.

If it helps, each page starts like this (this part I haven't edited)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]> <html lang="en-us" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>    <html lang="en-us" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>    <html lang="en-us" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9]>    <html lang="en-us" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 9]><!--> <html lang="en-us" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif] -->
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>This Particular Pages Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" >
    <link href="style/less/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/business-custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script><script src="selectivizr-min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the page, to reload the files vs reading from the cache? Try pressing ctrl +f5 when you see the old page.

Comment: IE loves to serve cached pages. You can use F12 and select always refresh from server in your developer tools.

Comment: I checked that out, but it doesn't work to clear the cache. It's certain pages that are loading improperly. it's generating all this content on the pages (viewing source), but the HTML files look different.

Comment: Please explain "sometimes it will revert to the old webpage".  Describe how the old page is different.

Comment: It's crazy. Everything is different. Different Navigation bar with different content, different background. I can't find the html page that pops up in the browser assembled anywhere on the whole drive, so it must be being generated by something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think IE uses caching.
By adding a random parameter to the URL the caching will be circumvented.

so e.g. www.mysite.nl?1
and then
www.mysite.nl?2 
etc.

Comment: Although this may create a fix, I don't think this should be marked as an acceptable answer. This is a hack if anything.